# How to find the number of TriggeredSends sent between a date by the name of the Trigger?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, c#, .net

I need to pull all TriggeredSends with the word "Confirmation" in the name of it that were sent between a specified date. The reason I need to pull by the name, and not an ID is because this is going to be used across multiple clients with different IDs. Our company has a naming standard that is used across all the accounts.

[TriggeredSendSummaries](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsendsummary/) have every property that I need to work with (UniqueOpens, UniqueClicks, etc). I can successfully pull the TriggeredSendSummaries of TriggeredSends, but I can't tell which TriggeredSend they are a summary of. I see that [TriggeredSendDefinitions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsenddefinition/) are a property of the summaries, and the definitions include the needed name I need to check for. The problem is I get an error saying that `Error: The Request Property(s) TriggeredSendDefintion do not match with the fields of TriggeredSendSummary retrieve`.

I know the issue is not the Date filter because I have that working in another API call perfectly fine.

Here is my .NET code if it helps anyone:

```
 RetrieveRequest triggeredRetrieveRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
 triggeredRetrieveRequest.ObjectType = "TriggeredSendSummary";
 triggeredRetrieveRequest.Properties = new String[] { "Sent", "UniqueOpens", "UniqueClicks", "CustomerKey", "TriggeredSendDefintion"}; //Fails on TriggeredSendDefinition

 SimpleFilterPart dateFilter = new SimpleFilterPart();
 dateFilter.Property = "SentDate";
 dateFilter.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.between;
 dateFilter.DateValue = new DateTime[2];

 //Parse date strings
 DateTime start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(myStartDate + " 00:00:00.000"), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var startKind = start.Kind;
 DateTime end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(myEndDate + " 00:00:00.000"), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var endKind = start.Kind;

 //Make input dates be included within the between
 dateFilter.DateValue[0] = start.AddDays(-1).ToLocalTime();
 dateFilter.DateValue[1] = end.AddDays(1).ToLocalTime();

 //Would like to add a complex filter here to check for name of TriggeredSendDefinition name

 triggeredRetrieveRequest.Filter = dateFilter;

 APIObject[] triggeredResults = null;
 String triggeredRequestId = null;
 String triggeredResponse = soapClient.Retrieve(triggeredRetrieveRequest, out triggeredRequestId, out triggeredResults);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right track, but turns out I needed to make a Request object for SentEvents, ClickEvents, etc. querying by the date and TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID as a complex filter.

Here's how to do it in C#:

```
 RetrieveRequest triggeredRetrieveRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
 triggeredRetrieveRequest.ObjectType = "SentEvent";
 triggeredRetrieveRequest.Properties = new String[] { "SendID", "EventDate" };

 //Create first simple filter for dates
 SimpleFilterPart dateFilter = new SimpleFilterPart();
 dateFilter.Property = "SentDate";
 dateFilter.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.between;
 dateFilter.DateValue = new DateTime[2];

 //Parse date strings
 DateTime start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(myStartDate + " 00:00:00.000"), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var startKind = start.Kind;
 DateTime end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(myEndDate + " 00:00:00.000"), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var endKind = start.Kind;

 //Make input dates be included within the between
 dateFilter.DateValue[0] = start.AddDays(-1).ToLocalTime();
 dateFilter.DateValue[1] = end.AddDays(1).ToLocalTime();

 //Create second part of complex filter for TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID
 SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
 sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
 sfp.Property = "TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID";
 sfp.Value = definitionIds.ToArray<string>();

 //Combine the two simple filters into one complex filter
 ComplexFilterPart cfp = new ComplexFilterPart();
 cfp.LeftOperand = sfp;
 dateFilter.Property = "EventDate";
 cfp.RightOperand = dateFilter;
 cfp.LogicalOperator = LogicalOperators.AND;

 retrieveRequest.Filter = cfp; //Set the complex filter to the request

 //Now make the actual request!
 APIObject[] results = null;
 String requestId = null;
 String response = null;
 int total = 0;

 do
 {
     response = soapClient.Retrieve(retrieveRequest, out requestId, out results);
     total += results.Length; //Add to the total of return results

     //Make a new ContinueRequest if needed
     retrieveRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
     retrieveRequest.ContinueRequest = requestId; 
 }
 while (response.Equals("MoreDataAvailable"));//This means there are more than 2500 records so keep looping
```

This can be done with SentEvents, OpenEvents, ClickEvents, BounceEvents, UnsubEvents, etc. so that you can actually count TriggeredSends between dates!